# Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to rotate an image using javascript  and I was trying some code I found on adobes website that does what I was looking for. When I run it it gives me the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

It keeps repeating every 5 second interval which is the amount of time between each image

Here is the javascript:

```
 (function () {
        var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  // change to match image ID
        var imageDir = 'images/';                          // change to match images folder
        var delayInSeconds = 5;                            // set number of seconds delay
        // list image names
        var images = ['image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image1.jpg'];

        // don't change below this line
        var num = 0;
        var changeImage = function () {
            var len = images.length;
            rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
            if (num == len) {
                num = 0;
            }
        };
        setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
    })();
```

and here is the html for the image:

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="rotating image" width="400" height="300" id="rotator" />
```

It shows the image1.jpg, but does not rotate it. Is there something blatantly obvious that I am not seeing? Wouldn't surprise me!

Thanks to anyone that can offer advice.

Comment: Where's the script? You may be encountering this if it is in the `head`.

Comment: Try passing rotator in your private function in changeImage.

Comment: it is in the head in the <script></script> tags

Comment: You need to wait for the DOM to be ready before you try and access elements. So, since your code's in the head, and is executed immediately, it tries to look for the `#rotator` element (in the body), which hasn't even been rendered yet, so the result of `document.getElementById("rotator")` is `null`, so of course you can't set the `src` property of `null`

Comment: Its trying to find an element with id `rotator` but it doesn't exist yet. Wrap it in a document ready event or run it after it has rendered

Comment: Is the DOM ready/loaded when this code runs?

Comment: @JoeW at that point the img object doesn't exist yet. Maybe you can move the script as the last element just before the </body>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in the `head` (look at the console):

http://jsfiddle.net/m2wce/

This happens because you are declaring the closure and executing right away. When you execute it in the `head`, the **DOM is not ready** (in other words, the HTML below still hasn't been "mounted" by the browser, as it processes the page sequencially, from top to botto) and at the time of the execution the `img` tag does not yet exist (because it is down below in the HTML page).

When in the `body`, after the referenced `img`, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/m2wce/1/

Comment: It may be clearer here, **look at the console**: (1) Code in `head` - before the `img` - not working: http://jsbin.com/ificir/2/edit and (2) code after the `img` - working: http://jsbin.com/ovuhet/2/edit .

Comment: Your answer saved me from 3 days of agony. Mentioning that 'DOM must be ready' was very vital in this answer. This is something I was not even aware of. and struggled with for 3 days. Thank you for this good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place this code after your dom gets ready. i.e inside `$(document).ready()` or on `window.onload`. as:

```
window.onload=function(){
(function () {
    var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  // change to match image ID
    var imageDir = 'images/';                          // change to match images folder
    var delayInSeconds = 5;                            // set number of seconds delay
    // list image names
    var images = ['image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image1.jpg'];

    // don't change below this line
    var num = 0;
    var changeImage = function () {
        var len = images.length;
        rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
        if (num == len) {
            num = 0;
        }
    };
    setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
})();
```

If you place that code inside anynomous function inside head (as you did), then it will not be able to load that image element from Dom because Dom would not be fully loaded at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is loaded before the body of your page, so the `rotator` element is not found. Remove the `var rotator = ...` line and put it inside the `changeImage` function instead:

```
(function () {
    var rotator;
    var rotatedImageId = 'rotator';           // change to match your HTML
    var imageDir = 'images/';
    var delayInSeconds = 5;
    // list image names
    var images = ['image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image1.jpg'];

    // don't change below this line
    var num = 0;
    var changeImage = function () {
        if (!rotator)
            rotator = document.getElementById(rotatedImageId);
        if (!rotator)
            return;

        var len = images.length;
        rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
        if (num == len) {
            num = 0;
        }
    };
    setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
})();
```

Comment: if you're going to do it like that, would be better as `var rotator; .... if (!rotator) { rotator = document.getElementById('rotator'); if (!rotator) { return; } }` type-thing.

Comment: @AD7six Great suggestion, thank you. I've added that piece to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I met this problems too.You can make `document.getElementById(rotatedImageId)` before you use that function. Another word,you can define rotator to gobal.
This is how i solved this problem.