# For loop to create an array and then pick random value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create an array from a for loop.  Once the array is created I need to pick a random value in the array to display.  In this case the values are pictures 1-4.png. I'm running into some trouble because the array looks like it's not being created, console says "Cannot set property 'src' of null".

```js
var imgstart = 1;
var imgend = 4;

var arrimg = [];

for (var i = imgstart; i < imgend+1; i++) {
  arrimg.push(i)
}

window.onload = choosePic;

function choosePic() {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrimg.length);
  document.getElementById("myPicture").src = arrimg[randomNum] + '.png';
}
```

```html
<img id="myPicture" />
```

Comment: The error tells you that there isn't an element with an ID 'myPicture'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set property 'src' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237142/cannot-set-property-src-of-null)

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well so we can see where `myPicture` is being referenced from?

Comment: Assure you have (if not create) an img-tag with id 'myPicture' <img id='myPicture' /> in your html.

Comment: Thanks very much, I put <img id='myPicture' /> in html and it works.  Now my only problem is that it says ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND because the random number in array does not have .png.  How can I add this to my code?

Comment: just add `'.png'` to the random selection like `document.getElementById("myPicture").src = arrimg[randomNum] + '.png';`